# get the visible text inside the div from a truncated message

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to get the visible text inside a div that is truncated.
For example: 
I have a really long message which is truncated at some point : 
"Test message test messa..."

I am looking for a way to retrieve only the text that is visible and not the entire message.

[i tried the jsbin and implemented in my code but seems to be having an issue as i am trying to do it in typescript react](http://jsbin.com/tirosozimi/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
$.fn.doOverflow = function(){
  return this[0].scrollWidth >  this.innerWidth()
}
$.fn.renderedText = function(){
  var o = s = this.text();
  console.log(s);
  console.log(s.length);
  while (s.length && this.doOverflow()){
    s = s.slice(0,-1);
  //  console.log(s);
    this.text(s+"…");
  //  console.log(this.text());
  }
  return s;
}

console.log($('#mySpan').renderedText())
```

```css
#mySpan{
  display:block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  width:150px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<span id=mySpan >This is the contents of the span tag.  It should truncate with an ellipsis if it is longer than 50px.</span>
<br>
  Open the console
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You can also add title attribute to span which will create tooltip to show the information, whenever user hovers on it

Comment: Instead of ellipsis, you can use shavejs https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/shave.. Then you can take the truncated text alone...

Answer (score 0):

If you can set text into an attribute then we can show a tooltip without using javascript.

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body{
font-family:arial;
}

#mySpan{

display:block;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #eee;
margin:10vh 5vh;
border-radius:3px;
position:relative;
}
#mySpan:before{
content:attr(data-content);
display:block;
white-space:nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
overflow:hidden;
}
#mySpan:hover::after{
position:absolute;
background:#333;
white-space: normal;
color:#fff;
top:calc(100% + 10px );
left:0;
padding:10px;
font-size:.85em;
content:attr(data-content);
display:block;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<span id="mySpan" data-content="This is the contents of the span tag.  It should truncate with an ellipsis if it is longer than 50px. Use text-overflow:ellipsis instead of javascript."> </span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am looking for a pure css solution. I know that the above solution works and that is what i shared in the code snippet. I am looking for similar functionality using pure CSS?

Comment: Load your content into a custom attribute and show the full content in pseudo elements when you hover. See the snippet.